# iOS UIBarButtonItem CustomView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I made a custom view as `leftBarButtonItem`, but it is not be left justified, I also find a `UInavigationBarBackIndicatorView` on the debugger but not visible, I want to alignment left with `UInavigationBarBackIndicatorView`.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(cancel)];
```

[Debuger View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjqh9.png)

[I wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC6Xj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you achieve what you are looking for.

```
UIButton *aBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
aBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = -13.0;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, aBtn, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                     target:self
                                                                     action:@selector(cancel)];
```

Do not forget to add an action to the button.